# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
I'm getting 3 eigenvalues 1, 1, 1 (all same) and
on solving for eigenvector I'm getting
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$x_{2}$=0
how to proceed further?

Comment: Google "Jordan matrix".

Comment: Find a basis for the null-space of the final matrix you've written. Since your matrix is already in the row echelon form, you can easily see 
 that $[1\;0\;0]^T$ and $[0\;0\;1]^T$ are eigenvectors.

Comment: You can only find two (linearly independent) eigenvectors. This matrix is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenspace is defined by the single linear equation $x_2$, so it has dimension $2$, and two obvious linearly independent eigenvectors are made up of the  first and last column of the matrix. The second column is a generalised eigenvector.